# I have this light and I don't know how to open it

Tags: ceiling, light-fixture

I would like to replace the bulb and I don't know how to do it. I tried pulling the clips on the side out, but they don't budge. Then I tried to unscrew the clips off (hence the third picture), but the screwdriver has to be used at an angle and won't unscrew. Any advice is appreciated.

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]
[image: Picture 3]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does the entire glass dome unscrew from the base? I had one like that once. It was even harder to put back together after I changed the bulb. Some also have spring clips that you just pull. There is a little resistance at first but then the spring wires open up, sort of the same was recessed lighting reflectors work.

Comment: Two other things to try. First, try sliding the curved piece (that's grabbing the glass) sideways under the piece with the screw in it. You can try gently tapping it with the plastic end of a screwdriver to see if it moves. Second, put the palm of your hand under the base of the glass and while pushing up, try turning it counterclockwise. If neither works, go to plan C and either borrow a small ratchet set or some nut drivers from a friend, or buy a cheap ratchet set. My guess is the size is either 1/4" or 5/16".

Comment: I have a fixture that looks almost identical to this - one of the 3 clips is on a spring and pulls out a little.  Then the cover just falls off.  Maybe its the same but the spring part is stuck on yours?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I had the same problem and couldn't work out how to get the cover off. One clip does pull out but they take a bit of effort to get it to shift enough to get the glass out. So glad I can now have light in the bathroom again. Ta.

Comment: Threw a Hail Mary search into Google and found this post. Thank you all for the answer. I would have never figured this out otherwise!

Comment: Is it glass or plastic? It looks like plastic, so try flexing it by pushing opposite sides to see if it slips over the little brackets.. Obviously if it's glass don't try this!!

Answer (score 14):

I have the same one...the definitive answer is as Grant says.  One of the clips pulls out enough to remove glass!  No screws or screwdrivers needed.

Comment: +1, I have *never* needed a socket wrench to change a light blub.

Comment: WARNING: There's a trick to it!  I have this very light and, at least in my case, maybe due to wear or lack of lubrication, I could have sworn (in fact I did, at least a couple times...) that none of the clips pulled out!  Finally, as things got a little more physical, I discovered that I had to LIFT the glass cover in order to free the locked up clip from whatever it was sticking on, and it pulled right out!  So that's my trick: LIFT and pull :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the clips is spring loaded.  Pull it out away from the dome, then slide the dome out from the other two stationary clips.  Be sure and support the under side of the dome while releasing the spring clip.

Answer (score 1):

For those who came here through Google and have a similar light, I just wanted to say: check the clips to make sure they're actually the same as the one here.

My light looks very similar from underneath so I thought the clips would come off the same, but it ended up having screws to loosen the clips instead of a spring. I only found out after tugging on the clips for a good five minutes and wondering why the heck none of the clips would budge. I even got the pliers out before realizing that I just needed a screwdriver (and subsequently feeling like an idiot).

Anyway, I thought I'd put this here in case it helps anyone.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Grant's answer was the best for me...but mine wasn't "spring loaded", 2 of the clips were welded onto the fixture while the third clip you're most interested in wasn't welded and so if you pushed it out from the middle there was more flexibility for it to move.....a little left/right action was needed as well. A little harder to put the cover back on.

Answer (score -1):

Taking a close look at the screw that holds the bracket in place seems to show that you will not get that out with a conventional screwdriver.

[image]

This looks to me as if it is a hex headed machine screw. As such, removal will require another type of tool like a 6-point socket or a nut driver as shown below:

[image]

[image]

Some sockets are available that have a flexible joint that permits their use in areas where straight in access to the fastener is not possible:

[image]

Be aware that sockets and nut drivers come in a variety of sizes and so it would be essential to obtain and use the proper tool.

---

Note: This fixture looks like it would be totally possible to remove the glass dome / dish from the light simply by removing just one of the brackets. You should check more closely at all three brackets. It is possible that one bracket is held in place with a different type of screw that is easier to remove with either thumb power or a standard screw driver.

Comment: +1 especially for the last point. Also, if that were not the case (that at least one clip was easy to remove), I would seriously consider replacing the whole fixture, because changing a light bulb should never be that difficult.