# How do I remove this so I can change the lightbulb?

Tags: light-fixture

This is a lot more complicated than I thought. I unscrewed the nipple, thinking the cover would slide right out, but no — nothing. Any ideas? I can't get a very good vantage point and am really hoping this can be done blindly from beneath.

[image: The culprit.]

Comment: possible duplicates: [How can I change the bulb in this three-clawed, ceiling-mounted dome light fixture?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/63212/33), [I have this light and I don't know how to open it](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/38394/33)

Answer (score 4):

Have a go at one of those three finger lookin' things holding the glass.   Unscrew the little bolt holding it it.  Or, more likely, one of them might be spring loaded.   Take care not to drop the glass.

Comment: They twisted right off once I gave 'em hell. Thanks!